# How to save rendered fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts

How would I save rendered fonts from websites? I tried ctrl + s on Chrome then saved the page and it didn't save the rendered font... I used inspect element on the saved page and there's a lot of these errors that say "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" about the fonts on console... Could someone please help me? I really want the fonts that [htmlBurger](https://htmlburger.com) uses on the text "YOUR CODING SERVICE" so that I can use it on my website.

Comment: You can try this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm) on chrome, but i suggest you to [use dev console](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that page (htmlBurger), just open DevTools (In Chrome it's `Ctrl+Shift+I`) and go to **Sources** tab. From right navigation go to: 
*htmlburger.com > assets > fonts/tungsten-rounded*

Then select font you want to download and right click it and choose *Open in new tab*. It should automatically download font.